# opening of file(pdf,png,jpeg) asscoiation with browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having a function which on calling window.open(URL),that URLis returning me a file. On clicking, once it's downloaded , i want to associate it with browser, means that file should only open in browser, but not with any default application preset by OS. Any leads on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: you should set the right content disposition form data

Comment: Thanks angelo :) , using inline disposition worked :)